# Database of Motor Vehicles?

Tags: data-request, transportation

Is there a database of the **Motor Vehicles** that were built until now, containing the

- Model
- Size
- Weight
- Price
- Year of release
- Power.
- Model engine
- Engine Capacity
- Position of the engine.
- Engine displacement.
- Maximum engine speed.
- Torque.
- Fuel system.
- Turbine
  and optionally any other specifications

It does not need to contain the data of [almost] all the Motor Vehicles, but at least the representative sample.

Motor Vehicles registered in all countries or just registered in any one particular country is also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasets of motor vehicles are available in different formats, but it wouldn't be easy to find vehicles dataset, including all of these details. You can no doubt find these details in the form of distinct files from Kaggle or find all vehicle models, manufacturer, manufacturing years and other details related to models from this dataset https://www.back4app.com/database/back4app/car-make-model-dataset. This source allows fetching data into a variety of frameworks including PHP, Java, Python etc.

However, to know about fuel, torque, maximum engine capacity, you would have to combine different files for web scraping. Or you can consider this reliable source https://www.teoalida.com/cardatabase/car-models-engines-dimensions/ but keep in mind, you can only find vehicles till 2016 here.